# How to get the source of an image when i click on that image in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the source of an image when i clicked inside li element.
please guide me on this.

```
<li class="k-tile" data-type="f" data-uid="504c365a-fd54-4a9f-adc2-c217ce4dc8fc" 
                                               role="option" aria-selected="false">
    <div class="k-thumb">
        <img class="k-image" alt="1.jpg" style="" 
                           src="http://doelbewust.nl/img/doelbewust_logo.png">
    </div>
    <strong>1.jpg</strong>
    <span class="k-filesize">206.97 KB</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the image of the clicked `li` and use the `attr()` function:

```js
$('li.k-tile').on('click', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var src = that.find('img').attr('src');
    alert(src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="k-tile" data-type="f" data-uid="504c365a-fd54-4a9f-adc2-c217ce4dc8fc" role="option" aria-selected="false">
    <div class="k-thumb">
        <img class="k-image" alt="1.jpg" style="" src="http://doelbewust.nl/img/doelbewust_logo.png">
    </div>
    <strong>1.jpg</strong>
    <span class="k-filesize">206.97 KB</span>
</li>
```

Comment: And when i change  li class="k-tile" to li class="k-tile k-state-selected" then what should i do

Comment: Nothing, the class "k-tile" still remains, you just add another class. So, the function will still alert the img src

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood you correctly

```
   $("img.k-image").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want to hook the event to the click of the `li`, you would need to use `find()` to retrieve the related `img` element and its `src`. Try this:

```
$('.k-tile').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('.k-image').prop('src');
    // do something with src...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <li class="k-tile" data-type="f" data-uid="504c365a-fd54-4a9f-adc2-c217ce4dc8fc" role="option" aria-selected="false">
        <div class="k-thumb">
            <img class="k-image" alt="1.jpg" style="" src="http://doelbewust.nl/img/doelbewust_logo.png">
        </div>
        <strong>1.jpg</strong>
        <span class="k-filesize">206.97 KB</span>
    </li>

    $(".k-thumb>img.k-image").click(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        alert(src);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2mc0xzq/

Answer (score 0):

you can use attr function in jquery and bind click event

```
$('img').on({
'click': function() {
     var src =  $(this).attr('src');
 }
});
```